# Integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate: $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}\text dx$$
I've typed this into wolframalpha as a result I received something with inverse hyperbolic sine. Is it possible to have it without this hyperbolic sine? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Just express the inverse hyperbolic sine by a logarithm, since $$\sinh x = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}.$$

Comment: what is wrong with the result which you got? $dx$ is missing

Comment: thus what will be the best method to integrate that?

Comment: See also: [How to compute the integral of $ \frac{\sqrt{(x^2+1)}}{x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1623501)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\tan\theta$

$$\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2}dx=\int\dfrac{\sec^3\theta}{\tan^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$=\int\dfrac{\cos\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

Set $\sin\theta=u$

Comment: In essence, $$x=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}u$$

Comment: Do you want $u=\sin\theta$?

Comment: @user84413, Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity:
$$\sinh^{-1}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$$
This is useful, because:
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2} 
&= \sinh^{-1}x - \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} + C \\
&= \boxed{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) - \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} + C}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$ I= \displaystyle \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2} \times \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx $$
$$\displaystyle I  = \int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx+\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$

Now in second Integral , Put $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{t}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dx = -\frac{1}{t^2}dt$

So we get   $$\displaystyle I  = \ln\left|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right|+J$$

So Integral $J$ Convert into $$\displaystyle -\int \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt\;,$$ Now Substitute $t^2+1=u^2\;,$ Then $tdt = udu$

So  Second Integral $J$ into $$\displaystyle -\int \frac{udu}{u} = -u=-\sqrt{t^2+1}=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}dx= \ln\left|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right|-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\tan\theta, dx=\sec^2\theta d\theta$ to get

$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}dx=\int\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan^2\theta}\cdot\sec^2\theta d\theta=\int\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan^2\theta}\big(\tan^2\theta+1\big)d\theta=\int\big(\sec\theta+\csc\theta\cot\theta\big)d\theta$

$=\displaystyle\ln\big|\sec\theta+\tan\theta \big|-\csc\theta+C=\ln\big(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\big)-\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}+C$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2} d x 
= & -\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\, d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
= & -\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} d x \quad (\textrm{ IBP })\\
= & -\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x }+\sinh ^{-1} x+C \quad (\textrm{ via }x=\sinh \theta)
\end{aligned}
$$